# Как получить список из двух JSON объектов

Tags: c#, json

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть два JSON объекта

```
{  
   "1228":{  
      "price":836,
      "reference":"243107210-01",
      "idn":1228
   },
   "1294":{  
      "price":864,
      "reference":"243607210-01",
      "idn":1294
   }
}

{  
   "1228":[  
      {  
         "id_image":"35298",
         "legend":""
      },
      {  
         "id_image":"35299",
         "legend":""
      },
      {  
         "id_image":"35300",
         "legend":""
      }
   ],
   "1294":[  
      {  
         "id_image":"35298",
         "legend":""
      },
      {  
         "id_image":"35299",
         "legend":""
      },
      {  
         "id_image":"35300",
         "legend":""
      }
   ]
}
```

У них есть общее поле "1228" и "1294". В итоге хочу получить список объектов с полями, например: Id = 1228, Ref = 243107210-01, Image = 35298, 35299.

Вопрос в том как можно сделать выборку из двух JSON объектов в один результирующий список.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LINQ`, хорошая вещь!

- Берем ваши два `JSON` и загоняем в `string` (будь то чтение из файла, либо с сервера, не важно).
- Далее определяем структуру каждого из них, в первом мы видим, что есть некий `Dictionary`, который содержит в виде ключа - `int`, а в виде значения определенную структуру данных, давайте это напишем: `Dictionary<int, RootOne>`

Сам `RootOne` - это класс, который определяет то, как будет выглядеть значение в нашем `Dictionary`:

```
public class RootOne
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public int Idn { get; set; }
}
```

- Отлично, со структурой первого `JSON` разобрались, что же со вторым? А с ним все тоже, но не совсем! Видно, что ключ нашего `Dictionary` аналогично первому имеет `int`, а вот значение тут уже некий список. Давайте напишем: `Dictionary<int, List<RootTwo>>`.

`RootTwo` в данном случае аналогично и с первым, структура каждого элемента в коллекции `List`:

> ```
> public class RootTwo {
>         [JsonProperty("id_image")]
>         public int ImageId { get; set; }
>         public string Legend { get; set; }
>     }
> ```
>
> Замечу, что использовал для удобства `JsonProperty`, который указывает на название оригинального значения в `JSON`, что нам в итоге
>   позволяет изменить само значение на более читаемое.

- Хорошо, структура обоих `JSON` есть! Нужно загрузить сами данные. Я буду использовать удобную для этого библиотеку JSON.NET:

---

```
var jsonOne = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, RootOne>>(jsonStrOne);// - Первый наш JSON, приведенный к Dictionary<int, RootOne>
var jsonTwo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, List<RootTwo>>>(jsonStrTwo);// - Второй JSON, приведенный к Dictionary<int, List<RootTwo>>
```

- Отлично, теперь перейдем к `LINQ` и добавим немного "магии"!

---

```
var query = from listOne in jsonOne
    from listTwo in jsonTwo
    where listOne.Key == listTwo.Key
    select new {Id = listOne.Key, Ref = listOne.Value.Reference, Images = listTwo.Value};
```

В данном примере я взял две коллекции, которые получились у нас при загрузки `JSON`, далее условие `where` гласит, что будут выбраны элементы, которые совпадают из первого `JSON` во втором по ключу!. Затем с помощью `select` мы создаем новую коллекцию, которая будет содержать в себе "выжимку" из двух `JSON` сразу.

Осталось только вывести:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Ref: {item.Ref}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Images: {string.Join(",", item.Images.Select(x=>x.ImageId))}");
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
}
```

Задачу можно по разному решить, к примеру можно не создавать новый объект, который будет объединять два `JSON`, а получать необходимые данные при проходе по первому циклом (тогда можно отказаться от созданного ранее `query`:

```
foreach (var one in jsonOne)
{
    var item = jsonTwo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == one.Key);
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {one.Key} ");
    Console.WriteLine($"Ref: {one.Value.Reference} ");
    Console.WriteLine($"Image: {string.Join(",", item.Value.Select(x=>x.ImageId))}");

    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
}
```

В общем экспериментируйте! Выложил весь готовый код: [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3mxVlI). Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а я пробовал через JObject, не хотел делать десериализацию, но тогда через LINQ не получилось.